# Is there a way to create persistent bullets in Power Point?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, formatting, xml, styles, bullets

I have added three custom bullets to the Style Master Text placeholder, however, I would like to have a choice to choose one of those three bullets on the fly. These come in a custom font.

This will be a template sent out to 50 employees and I don't want them to have to go the extra steps in selecting a custom bullet each time, depending on which they prefer to use.

Is there a way to make them default or persistent so that it's a quick selection from the bullets menu?

I am open to "hacking" the XML.

[image]

Comment: You can add custom bullets to the bullets library : [Add a picture bullet or symbol to the Bullet Library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-bullets-with-pictures-or-symbols-a6bf04a8-be3d-4bec-969a-6196e89da741). Is that an answer?

Comment: That is for Microsoft Word, I can't find that option in Power Point

Comment: If you do it in Word, does it carry over to PowerPoint?

Comment: Does not carry through.

Answer (score 0):

In Word you can
[Create custom bullets with pictures or symbols](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-bullets-with-pictures-or-symbols-a6bf04a8-be3d-4bec-969a-6196e89da741)
in order to add a picture bullet or symbol to the Bullet Library.
Unfortunately, this does not work for PowerPoint.

In PowerPoint, you need to
[Create and save a PowerPoint template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-a-powerpoint-template-ee4429ad-2a74-4100-82f7-50f8169c8aca):

> When you create a presentation and then save it as a PowerPoint template (`.potx`) file, you can share it with your colleagues and reuse it again. To create a template, you'll need to modify a slide master and a set of slide layouts.

The process is described in the article in detail and with screenshots.

Comment: I didn't ask how to create a PowerPoint template, I asked how to make bullet points persistent. if I set a bullet point in a master slide or use one somewhere on the presentation it will only be visible among the bullets library where its being used. If I want to use that bullet again some where else, I will have to go through the tedious process of selecting it from symbols.

Comment: Office is a pretty frustrating product, without much conformity. The PowerPoint team didn't provide any other method, except basing the presentation on a template that contains that bullet. This is a Microsoft product, not very programmable by users wherever the developers didn't foresee a need.